# Calling generic method with Type variable

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method

```
Foo<T>
```

I have a Type variable `bar`

Is it possible to achieve something like `Foo<bar>`

Visual Studio is expecting a type or namespace at the bar.

Comment: Can you show some code where you attempting to use it? It's definetely possible, so it's likely a syntax error.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Lets assume that Foo is declared in class Test such as

```
public class Test
{
   public void Foo<T>() { ... }

}
```

You need to first instantiate the method for type `bar` using [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx). And then invoke it using reflection.

```
var mi = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo");
var fooRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(bar);
fooRef.Invoke(new Test(), null);
```

Comment: What if class Test is static ? How to invoke fooRef ?

Comment: @Riomare, sorry for delayed response!. The first parameter to `Invoke` method is the instance on which method needs to be called on. For static methods, there will be no instance and hence null to passed e.g. `fooRef.Invoke(null, null)`

Answer (score 62):

If I understand your question correctly, you have, in essence, the following types defined:

```
public class Qaz
{
    public void Foo<T>(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

public class Bar { }
```

Now, given you have a variable `bar` defined as such:

```
var bar = typeof(Bar);
```

You then want to be able to call `Foo<T>`, replacing `T` with your instance variable `bar`.

Here's how:

```
// Get the generic method `Foo`
var fooMethod = typeof(Qaz).GetMethod("Foo");

// Make the non-generic method via the `MakeGenericMethod` reflection call.
// Yes - this is confusing Microsoft!!
var fooOfBarMethod = fooMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { bar });

// Invoke the method just like a normal method.
fooOfBarMethod.Invoke(new Qaz(), new object[] { new Bar() });
```

Enjoy!

Comment: +1 ... just a little later than accepted answer but wonderfully put!

Comment: @`Daniel Elliot` - Yes, I know - 41 seconds later. I was hoping that my slightly more detailed answer would prevail, but alas. ;-)

Comment: my code get work, best  answer in detail.... Thanks

Comment: doesn't work.  first line returns null

Comment: @AndrewGray - I test everything before posting.