# Call generic method c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

how to call generic method, I heard about reflection, but I think I'm doing some wrong, check please.

```
 public static LinkedListNode<T> MergeSortLL<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
    {

        if (Head == null || Head.Next == null)
        {
            return Head;
        }
        LinkedListNode<T> middle = GetMiddle<T>(Head);
        LinkedListNode<T> half = middle.Next;
        middle.Next = null;

        return Merge(Head, half);

    }
```

And here i'm trying to invoke my generic method with parameters

```
    public void MSort()
    {
        Type type = typeof(MergeSort);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(MergeSort).GetMethod("MergeSortLL");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        generic.Invoke(null, null);
    }
```

**Update 2.**
Here more info what I've in my class MergeSort and why i'm using IComparable

```
class MergeSort
{

    public static LinkedListNode<T> MergeSortLL<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
    {

        if (Head == null || Head.Next == null)
        {
            return Head;
        }
        LinkedListNode<T> middle = GetMiddle<T>(Head);
        LinkedListNode<T> half = middle.Next;
        middle.Next = null;

        return Merge(Head, Head, half);

    }

    public static LinkedListNode<T> Merge<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head, LinkedListNode<T> Left, LinkedListNode<T> Right) where T : IComparable<T>
    {

        LinkedListNode<T> mHead = Head;
        LinkedListNode<T> curr = mHead;

        while (Left != null && Right != null)
        {
            if (Left.Value.CompareTo(Right.Value) <= 0)
            {
                curr.Next = Left;
                Left = Left.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr.Next = Right;
                Right = Right.Next;
            }
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
        curr.Next = (Left == null) ? Right : Left;

        return mHead.Next;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<T> GetMiddle<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (Head == null)
        {
            return Head;
        }

        LinkedListNode<T> slow, fast;
        slow = fast = Head;
        while (fast.Next != null && fast.Next.Next != null)
        {
            slow = slow.Next; fast = fast.Next.Next;
        }
        return slow;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can look at the post in stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957817/calling-generic-method-with-type-variable

Comment: Just `var result = MergeSort.MergeSorLL(HeadNodeOfLinkedList);`  The generics will be infer

Comment: Generics and reflection don't mix well.  If you don't know the type, you can't really do anything with the _output_ at compile time.  If you do, then there's no need to use reflection, just call it as @juharr suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the comments you're leaving and the issues you are running into. It seems to me that you're intention is to pass the LinkedList to this method, so it should be:

```
public static LinkedListNode<T> MergeSortLL<T>(LinkedList<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Then you should just be invoked like this:

```
var head = new LinkedList<int>();

MergeSortLL<int>(head)
```

You see I've set the `int` as the type I want the method to be constrained to.

However, because you will have a strongly typed `LinkedList` the C# compiler will implicitly set the `<int>` on the `MergeSortLL` method reducing the call to:

```
MergeSortLL(head);
```

You've also put a generic constraint on the genereic type T, make sure that whatever type your are using inherits from `IComparable<T>` which when saying out loud sounds a little strange, but seems right.

Comment: I think `MergeSort`is the class that contains the method, not necessarily the type that is held in the generic linked list.

Comment: reading the way he has invoked the method, it would believe me to think what i've done. However, I'm more inclined to agree with you... It's just entirely clear from the OP.

Comment: I'm basing it on the `typeof(MergeSort).GetMethod("MergeSortLL")`

Comment: Yes, MergeSort is class, I've input `MergeSort.MergeSortLL<MergeSort>(Head);` and have error that `cannot convert from 'task.LinkedListNode<T>' to 'task.LinkedListNode<task.MergeSort>`

Comment: @Vitaliy You're giving the wrong type.  It should be `MergeSort.MergeSortLL(Head);`, let it infer the generic type from whatever `Head` is.

Comment: Updated based on @Vitaliy comments

Comment: Have try your solution but, have another error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'task.LinkedList<int>' to 'task.LinkedListNode<int>' task`

Comment: @Vitaliy You need to pass the head of the `LinkedList` like this `MergeSort.MergeSortLL(list.First)`.  Or change the method to take a `LinkedList<T>` instead of `LinkedListNode<T>`.

Comment: I've updated my answer in alignment with the new comments.

Comment: @juharr Oh yeah, missed that. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `LinkedList<T>` just pass it's head (via the `First` property) to the method and the types will be inferred.

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>();
var head = list.First; 
var sorted = MergeSort.MergeSortLL(head);
```

Assuming that `MergeSort` is a static class you could make it an extension method by adding `this` before the `LinkedListNode<T> Head` parameter and then it could be called as if it were an instance method.

```
var sorted = head.MergeSortLL();
```