# Passing types to function in c#

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, typeof

I am using .net core 2.1 with entityframework core.

I have different models/entities/types defined in my project. e.g. Student, Class, Teacher.

I am getting the table data for these models to set in my cache.

At the moment, I am doing this;

```
string[] tablesToBeCached  = { "Student", "Class", "Teacher" };

foreach(var table in tablesToBeCached)
{
     cache.Set(key, GetTableData(dbContext, table));
}
```

and the function GetTableData() is defined as follows;

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetTableData(DBContext dbContext, string tableName)
{
      switch (tableName)
      {
          case "Student":
              return dbContext.Student;

          case "Class":
              return dbContext.Class;

          case "Teacher":
              return dbContext.Teacher;

          default:
              return null;
       }
  }
```

I want this code to be smart and short.

I tried following, but didn't work; (The error is 'x' is a variable but is used like a type)

```
List<object> entities = new List<object> { typeof(Student), typeof(Class), typeof(Teacher) };
entities.ForEach(x => GetTableData(x, dbContext));

public IEnumerable<object> GetTableData(object x, DBContext dbContext)
{
     return dbContext.Set<x>();
}
```

Can someone please help? Is it even possible in C#?

Comment: Are the tables to be cached known at compile time?

Comment: _"I tried following, but didn't work;"_ Did not work is not a sufficient problem description. Please add what type of problem you have. What you expect and what you get. ErrorMesages? Stacktraces? ...

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't _ever_ be returning a collection of `object`, unless you have a very good reason to. The whole point of a strongly typed language is that you know exactly what types you are working with. Don't make one method that returns a multitude of data types - you'll have a hard time parsing it later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling generic method with Type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957817/calling-generic-method-with-type-variable)

Comment: The error is 'x' is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: btw: Caching is hard. Why reinvent the wheel? When there are tested solutions like  [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)? (Not affiliated)

Comment: Caching is not hard at all in .net core. Built in, [in-memory cache](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3230129/how-to-use-in-memory-caching-in-aspnet-core.html) is very easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out in the comments, you should go with generics:

```
cache.Set(key1, GetTableData<Student>(dbContext));
cache.Set(key2, GetTableData<Class>(dbContext));
cache.Set(key3, GetTableData<Teacher>(dbContext));


public static IEnumerable<T> GetTableData<T> (DBContext dbContext)
{
     return dbContext.Set<T>();
}
```

To avoid writing the same code (`cache.Set`) foreach entity, you can use reflection, but your entities should implement some kind of common interface or base class.

For example, suppose your entities implement a common interface `IEntity`:

```
interface IEntity {}

class Student: IEntity {}

class Teacher: IEntity {}
```

then you can

1 retrieve all the types that implement IEntity:

```
var type = typeof(IEntity);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

2 call the GetTableData method in this way:

```
MethodInfo method = GetType.GetMethod("GetTableData ");

foreach (var entityType in types)
{
    MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
    genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Comment: The GetTableData() bit is fine in your answer. Can you please show how to use foreach loop to call this  method, as I have 50 other entities (with static small data set, so do not worry about cache getting explode) in my project and I do not want to write 50 times the cache.Set() line. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks, I have implemented very similar solution to yours. Special thanks to @gunr2171 for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented very similar solution as @Alberto answered (but I have avoided IEntity interface bit). Special thanks to @gunr2171 for pointing to the right direction. My solution is as follows;

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(CacheSettings).GetMethod("GetTableData");
string[] tablesToBeCached  = { "Student", "Class", "Teacher" };
object[] parameters = new object[] { myDBContextObj };

foreach(var tblToBeCached in tablesToBeCached)
{
    string key = $"{tblToBeCached}";
    MethodInfo getTableDataMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType($"Namespace.{tblToBeCached}, AssemblyName"));
    cache.Set(key, getTableDataMethod.Invoke(null, parameters));
}

and the GetTableData() method is just one liner (Happy days )

public static IEnumerable<T> GetTableData<T>(MyDBContext dbContext) where T : class
{
   return dbContext.Set<T>();
}
```